# Why yolo can't detect all objects in image?

Tags: machine-learning, image-processing, object-detection, yolo, darknet

I am trying to detect objects in image using AlexeyAB darknet.But it is detecting only 2 or 3 object.It can't detect small objects(for example hat).I am using this command:

`./darknet detector test ./cfg/coco.data ./cfg/yolov3.cfg /weight_path/ /image_path/`

How can I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [AlexeyAB page](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet#how-to-improve-object-detection) for small objects you can do this:

> for training for small objects (smaller than 16x16 after the image is
>   resized to 416x416) - set layers = -1, 11 instead of
>   https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet/blob/6390a5a2ab61a0bdf6f1a9a6b4a739c16b36e0d7/cfg/yolov3.cfg#L720
>   and set stride=4 instead of
>   https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet/blob/6390a5a2ab61a0bdf6f1a9a6b4a739c16b36e0d7/cfg/yolov3.cfg#L717

For training small and large objects you can use modified models:

> - Full-model: 5 yolo layers:    https://raw.githubusercontent.com/AlexeyAB/darknet/master/cfg/yolov3_5l.cfg
> - Tiny-model: 3 yolo layers:    https://raw.githubusercontent.com/AlexeyAB/darknet/master/cfg/yolov3-tiny_3l.cfg
> - Spatial-full-model: 3 yolo layers:    https://raw.githubusercontent.com/AlexeyAB/darknet/master/cfg/yolov3-spp.cfg

Also after training is done, in the detection phase, you may do the following:

> Increase network-resolution by set in your .cfg-file (height=608 and
>   width=608) or (height=832 and width=832) or (any value multiple of 32)
>   - this increases the precision and makes it possible to detect small objects: [link](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet/blob/0039fd26786ab5f71d5af725fc18b3f521e7acfd/cfg/yolov3.cfg#L8-L9)
>
> - it is not necessary to train the network again, just use    .weights-file already trained for 416x416 resolution
> - but to get even greater accuracy you should train with higher    resolution 608x608 or 832x832, note: if error Out of memory occurs
>     then in .cfg-file you should increase subdivisions=16, 32 or 64: [link](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet/blob/0039fd26786ab5f71d5af725fc18b3f521e7acfd/cfg/yolov3.cfg#L4)

Comment: Is the size must be equal, height =width, or not equal. For example I have image in 331×92. Should I choose near number that can divide by 32 or just choose 416×416 or 608×608 ect. Any help to set my images resizing?

Comment: @N.white width and height don't have to be the same, but it's better for both of them to be multiples of 32.